# What is Reusable State?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was looking for an exact definition or a document that describes what a Reusable State is, but I didn't find it. I read: [Strict Mode: Ensuring reusable state](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state),  [How to support Reusable State in Effects](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18) and [Adding Reusable State to StrictMode](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/19) did not find an exact definition there. Which state exactly will be reusable. Is this a State created using useState and useRef? Or some other.

I undestand that with the new React features such as the Offscreen API and React Refresh, the component should be adapted to multiple state-preserving mounts. And for this a new behavior for Strict Mode was added in React 18  (mount -> unmount -> mount). But I have not found a document that describes a Reusable State.

Answer (score 0):

The first paragraph of your first link describes it and its motivation:

> In the future, we’d like to add a feature that allows React to add and remove sections of the UI while preserving state. For example, when a user tabs away from a screen and back, React should be able to immediately show the previous screen. To do this, React will support remounting trees using the same component state used before unmounting.

It's state that's available after the component is unmounted.

Comment: Thak you but this is not what I asked for. My question what kind of state is created that will remain after unmounting, using useState and useRef, or you can do something else.